# Works on localhost but not live site. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, jquery, json, paypal

Anyone know what this error is indicating?

This script (paypal php virtual terminal) works great testing on localhost, but when I transfer the files to my web server the jquery/json hangs.

```
index.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.n.parseJSON (http://www..com/virtualterminal/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:4:5309)
at Object.success (http://www..com/virtualterminal/js/validate.js:80:46)
at j (http://www..com/virtualterminal/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:26911)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://www..com/virtualterminal/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:27724)
at x (http://www..comvirtualterminal/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:4:11065)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://www..com/virtualterminal/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:4:14577)n.parseJSON @ jquery.js:7517success @ validate.js:80j @ jquery.js:3094fireWith @ jquery.js:3206x @ jquery.js:8259(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8600
```

I'm checking the log files, and it looks like the sandbox payment is processing correctly... the only issue is that the jquery/json is not redirecting to the success page.

Comment: Log your request response before you parse it. I'm going to guess it's really XML, not JSON.

Comment: I means that the thing you're trying to parse as json has an unexpected token `<` at position 0. Aka: "Your JSON seems to start with a `<` which means it's either not JSON, or it's got some bad data preceding it."

Comment: But why does it work perfectly fine on my localhost, but outputs this error on my webserver?

Comment: Hard to tell without code and seeing the actual response.

Comment: Right.. posted the response on the answer below. Everything is resulting in success besides this one error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Anyone know what this error is indicating?*

The error you got is just because the expected response is not a json but seems to be an xml based page. That could be some html output indicating some error for the processing has been done.

So, eventually that is an error page, which has some html code written and that's contains `<` at position 0, which is `<!doctype ...>`.

Comment: Besides the php includes statement, the first non-php line is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and the error is indicating on index.php line 1.  But my question is why is this not working on my webserver, and working fine on my localhost? I basically copied it from github and I'm pretty sure it's not an error with the script...

Comment: That has to be traced that what is the response php is returning. It could be possible php code is causing some error which is producing error html. You can find out the response in the network tab in inspector tool.

Comment: Oh I see.  Tested the response on localhost and it's a success with no error.  On my webhost it's getting an error `Notice:  Undefined index: cc_expdate in /home/public_html/virtualterminal/bin/process.php on line 779` which is just simply `'card_expiration' => $_SESSION['cc_expdate'],`  Now I'm even more confused because I'm using the exact same information on both instances but only getting the error on my webserver...

Comment: changed it to `'card_expiration' => (isset($_SESSION['cc_expdate']) ? $_SESSION['cc_expdate'] : null),` and it's working now on webserver... have to do more testing but I think this is just for the return data, and not for the actual payment process... but thank you for helping me pinpoint this down

Comment: Glad helping you somehow.